# Как правильно вывести многоуровневое меню?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет, как мне правильно вывести мое многоуровневое меню.

Тут два метода , первый метод строит дерево (рекурсия), второй метод вытаскивает все категории с БД. Как правильно вывести во VIEW меню и что бы он был в `<option value="">Выбрать категорию</option>`.

Когда вывожу и делаю перебор массива, то теряю многоуровневою вложенность, третий уровень не появляется и использовать много foreach тоже как то не умно?

Это модель Category

```
/**
 * Строим дерево
 * @param $data
 * @param int $parent_id
 * @return array
 */
protected function buildTree($data, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $node) {
        if ($node['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            unset($data[$id]);
            $node['childs'] = $this->buildTree($data, $node['id']);
            $tree[] = $node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

/**
 * Получаем категории
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllCategories()
{
    $data = self::find()->asArray()->all();
    $data = $this->buildTree($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Вот пример во вьюхе.

```
Если просто сделать вардамп без форича
Меню
--- меню
--- меню
--- меню
Меню
--- меню
--- меню
--- меню
Меню
--- меню
--- меню
--- меню
```

А мне надо вот так

```
Меню
--- меню
    --- меню
    --- меню
--- меню
--- меню
Меню
--- меню
--- меню
    --- меню
    --- меню
--- меню
Меню
--- меню
--- меню
--- меню
```

третья вложенность не работает или я не знаю как сделать бесконечную вложенность

```
<select id="category-parent_id" class="form-control" name="Category[parent_id]" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Выбрать категорию</option>

        <?php foreach ($category->getAllCategories() as $cats) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $cats['id'] ?>"><?= $cats['title'] ?></option>

            <?php if ($cats['childs'] > 0) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($cats['childs'] as $cat) : ?>
                    <option value="<?= $cat['id'] ?>">--- <?= $cat['title'] ?></option>

                    <?php if ($cat['childs'] > 0) : ?>
                        <?php foreach ($cat['childs'] as $childs) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $childs['id'] ?>">--- <?= $childs['title'] ?></option>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>


    </select>
```

А если распечатать getAllCategories(), что тогда получается? -> вот что получается

```
[
0 => [
    'id' => '1'
    'parent_id' => '0'
    'title' => 'Протеин'
    'childs' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => '4'
            'parent_id' => '1'
            'title' => 'Казеин'
            'childs' => [
                0 => [
                    'id' => '29'
                    'parent_id' => '4'
                    'title' => 'Протос'
                    'childs' => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
        1 => [
            'id' => '5'
            'parent_id' => '1'
            'title' => 'Сывороточный протеин'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        2 => [
            'id' => '6'
            'parent_id' => '1'
            'title' => 'Соевый протеин'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        3 => [
            'id' => '7'
            'parent_id' => '1'
            'title' => 'Яичный протеин'
            'childs' => []
        ]
    ]
]
1 => [
    'id' => '2'
    'parent_id' => '0'
    'title' => 'Аминокислоты'
    'childs' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => '8'
            'parent_id' => '2'
            'title' => 'Комплексные'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        1 => [
            'id' => '9'
            'parent_id' => '2'
            'title' => 'Отдельные'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        2 => [
            'id' => '10'
            'parent_id' => '2'
            'title' => 'Глюкомин'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        3 => [
            'id' => '11'
            'parent_id' => '2'
            'title' => 'Цитруллин'
            'childs' => [
                0 => [
                    'id' => '12'
                    'parent_id' => '11'
                    'title' => 'Комплексные'
                    'childs' => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
2 => [
    'id' => '25'
    'parent_id' => '0'
    'title' => 'Витамины и минералы'
    'childs' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => '26'
            'parent_id' => '25'
            'title' => 'Минералы'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        1 => [
            'id' => '27'
            'parent_id' => '25'
            'title' => 'Омега 3'
            'childs' => []
        ]
        2 => [
            'id' => '28'
            'parent_id' => '25'
            'title' => 'Отдельные'
            'childs' => []
        ]
    ]
]
```

]

Comment: А как выглядит само дерево?

Comment: Используйте рекурсию для этого.

Comment: у меня есть рекурсия она в модели buildTree

Comment: добавил выглядит дерево

Comment: А если распечатать getAllCategories(), что тогда получается?

Comment: распечатка вверху

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, вы пытаетесь вывести поле `select`. К сожалению возможности этого элемента довольно скромные и позволяют создать только один уровень визуальной вложенности с помощью `optgroup`. Но вы можете использовать неразрывные пробелы `&nbsp;` чтобы отбивать вложенные подразделы. Рассчитайте префикс состоящий из неразрывных пробелов в соответствии с уровнем вложенности, используя `str_repeat`.

UPD:

Вам совершенно правильно советуют рекурсию.

```
function forEachCategory(callable $func, $categories, $depth = 0) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $func($category, $depth);
        $children = $category['childs']?? [];
        if ( ! empty($children)) {
            forEachCategory($func, $children, $depth + 1); // рекурсия
        }
    }
}

forEachCategory(function($category, $depth) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', 4 * $depth), $category['title'], "\n";
}, $cats);
```

Comment: та даже не в селект, как мне вывести многоуровневое меню, я просто этого не понимаю, код на верху, там есть ошибка, я незнаю как исправить

Comment: @Uman добавил пример рекурсивного обхода. Для HTML замените обычный пробел в выводе на `&nbsp;`

Comment: подождите у меня в модели есть метод рекурсия и там все отлично, проблема вывода во вьюху

Comment: @Uman вы понимаете, что такое рекурсия? Это просто приём, способ. В модели вы применяете его, чтобы собрать дерево по ссылкам parent_id, а в моём примере рекурсия применяется для того, чтобы последовательно получить доступ ко всем узлам этого дерева и, например, вывести их на экран. Если вы хотите обойтись без рекурсии, то вам следует формировать не дерево, а другую структуру. Но вы попробуйте рекурсию, она стоит того, чтобы использовать её несколько раз :-)